# Do I need Apple meta tags when I have a manifest?

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps, meta-tags, manifest.json

### Background Information

I create progressive web apps and try to make my websites backwards compatible *(excluding **ancient** software, such as IE* *)* and as a result, I like to keep old code when adding new code. I have made iOS web apps before and have done so using the meta tags; however, manifests have now been introduced and I was wondering whether it would be good to keep Apple meta tags for backwards compatibility or whether manifests were supported on all versions of iOS.

### Questions

**Do I still need to include the *web app capable* meta tag for it to work or will the manifest allow it to be standalone?**

```html
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

**Do I still need to include an icon and startup image or will iOS take icons from the manifest?**

```html
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="secure/apple-touch-startup-image.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd still have the meta tag, especially when it's kept for android. It's also worth keeping for people still on older versions of IOS and as a fallback because it is still supported. I'd also recommend using an ico for the favicon that's the same and include resolutions up to 256px. You can use `<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` for android and view the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html) for IOS.